Podman container with mediawiki can't connect to mariadb
I have a podman container with a mediawiki inside and a mariadb natively installed. So far it is running and I can access the web-interface.
But when I try to connect to the database during the setup phase, I get
Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'mediawikidbuser'@'mediawiki' (using password: YES)

Now the "fun" thing is, that I can connect to the database from inside the container. For debugging purposes I installed mariadb inside the container. From there I connected to the database outside and it works flawlessly. I can create tables, insert data and read them again.
In short terms: I can connect to the database from inside the container, but mediawiki can't.
I tried both: IP and hostname. Same error.
An alternative solution would be the use of postgresql, which is better in every way. But I couldn't get this working either. Per default the mediawiki container doesn't offer postgresql and the scripts for manually preparing the database don't run inside the container (even with tweaks). The docu says, mediawiki needs to be compiled (?) with the postgres-option.

Is it a good idea to run interactive setup in a container?

@AlexanderMashin I'm very willing to pick an alternative. How do I do it? Where can I find information about the non-interactive setup procedure?

Do you use pasta? Is mediawiki running in a custom network? Do you use rootless podman? Which podman version do you use? Do you use quadlets? or maybe docker-compose? or neither?

I wrote some podman documentation about connecting to localhost and the host's main interface

For non-interactive setup you could interactively create a dummy MediaWiki database once, dump it to an .sql file, manually compose LocalSettings.php for a containerised setup (possibly, by altering the file created by manual setup), import the .sql file in the container and run maintenance/update.php.

Also, have a look at this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_MediaWiki#Alternatives_to_manual_installation.

I did look around and tried several configurations with the maintenance/install.php. In the end it did work. But the css didn't work, 404. Then I retried the web-installer and with that it worked. Unfortunately, I don't see any thing, that I did differently or didn't try in the three hours before creating this post. I don't know, what did the thing, but it works now.
